# ParserException for XML file with ampersands using VTD-XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, vtd-xml, kanji

I am attempting to parse the JMDict_e.xml file from the JMDict project using VTD-XML. However, I am running into a parsing error.

The only error message that appears is:

```
ParserException: com.ximpleware.EntityException: Errors in Entity: Illegal entity char
```

A short excerpt from the xml looks like:

```
<entry>
    <ent_seq>1279770</ent_seq>
    <k_ele>
        <keb>構成要素</keb>
    </k_ele>
    <r_ele>
        <reb>こうせいようそ</reb>
    </r_ele>
    <sense>
        <pos>&n;</pos>
        <pos>&adj-no;</pos>
        <field>&comp;</field>
        <gloss>components</gloss>
        <gloss>elements</gloss>
        <gloss>parts</gloss>
    </sense>
</entry>
```

I believe that in the `pos` fields, the illegal characters are likely the ampersands. Is there a way to have vtd-xml to not treat these ampersands as special characters? Or is there a different approach to this problem?

Comment: XML doesn't allow ampersands; perhaps if you replace with "&amp;", that will help. I am not familiar with vtd-xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VTD-XML only recognizes those built-in character entities. It seems to me that most of the entities are invalid. You probably need to fix those problems before feeding it to the parser.

Comment: Thanks! I went through the file and removed the ampersands and then vtd-xml was able to parse it.